# Lists inside lists when reading from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is my code:

```
names = []

filename = "names.csv"
filedir = ""
csv_file = os.path.join(filedir, filename)

with open(csv_file) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        name = row
        names.append(name)

print(names)
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
[['hello'], ['hello'], ['one'], ['two'], ['three']]
```

The output I want is:

```
['hello', 'hello', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

I don't know why this is happening. If you can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we see the structure of the CSV file?

Comment: You gave the outlput, but we need to know the input as well!

Comment: every row is a list even if there is only one element in row - so your result is natural.

Comment: The clean way suggests to use `csv`, of course. But you're reading from a plaintext file and you know your separator - basically you could define own ways to get the desired data in the way you want. But before doing so: Print out `reader` and `row`, see what type they are and check the content format. You will see the list structures you get and then be able to either loop trough them, or direct append values using their index, like `names.append(row[0])`. That's just a general thought, without knowing the csv content.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on names:

```
x=[['hello'], ['hello'], ['one'], ['two'], ['three']]
t = []
for i in x:
    for j in i:
     t.append(j)
```

or you can do the below in your case:

```
names = []
for row in reader:
    names.append(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

using default list:

```
new_names = [name for names_list in names for name in names_list]
```

using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
new_names = np.array(names).flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `csv.reader` iterates through the rows as lists. 
It seems you only have a single element in each row of your csv?

If that is indeed the case, and is always the case, you can do two different things:

1)

```
with open(csv_file) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        name = row
        names.append(name[0])
```

2)

```
with open(csv_file) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        name = row
        names.extend(name)
```

Extend unpacks an iterable into the list.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way to do this:

```
for row in reader:
    [name] = row
    names.append(name)
print names
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
names = [['hello'], ['hello'], ['one'], ['two'], ['three']]

list(map(lambda x: x[0], names))
```